# Can't get all the posts from DB (Laravel Corcel with Wordpress)

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a very specific problem with querying all the posts from DB with eloquent. I have a Wordpress Database and Laravel with Corcel package (great work by the way!).

My site was active more than year, so I have more than 25 000 ID's in the posts table and there's no problem to retrieve post by category or by date, type, whatever... the problem is, that I somehow can't get the very latest posts - to be specific, the latest post I can get is from 05.01.2018 (4 month old posts)

```
$posts = Post::status('publish')
                ->type('post')
                ->with('taxonomies')
                ->with('thumbnail')
                ->newest()
                ->paginate(20);
```

This is the code to retrieve the latest 20 posts, which works great (not too much queries, all is just fine), but as I said, the latest posts are 4 months old.

4 months earlier I made some redesign of that Wordpress site, I've switched the theme for my own, added custom fields for all the posts, made couple of custom post types. I can't figure it out what's wrong, I cleared all the cache, restart the server, everything, but something is wrong.

Also I can't even retrieve single post by ID with:

```
Post::find(id);
```

It's working for every post before that date. After 05.01.2018 it just returns null and the record in the DB exists. I'm really confused by now. If someone has an idea how to solve this, I would buy him/her a beer.

Comment: Did you log the executed query? Does `Post` have any scopes?

Comment: I tried to make a query with following method - withoutGlobalScope but still the same result. The records are there, but I can't get them.

Comment: What's the result of `\DB::enableQueryLog(); Post::find(id); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`?

Comment: I've got an empty array. I tried couple of different ID's but the result is an empty array.

Comment: The query log is empty?

Comment: Yes Jonas, I've just got a blank page with []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171646/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-madmatt).